# Struggling with debug asserts with mem alloc for SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA

Tags: c++, setupapi

I'm struggling with some debug asserts when my test program exits.  The purpose is to get the device path to a disk drive through using the Setup API.  This I'm doing.  I'm following the rule described [here for SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) i.e. calling SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() to determine the size needed for the structure, and allocating memory for the structure and calling SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() again.

This process works and I'm getting the data that I need.  What is not working correctly is, when the program exits, or I delete the memory directly, I get a debug assertion.  The assert window has the file where the problem was found, dbgdel.cpp, on line 52.  The problem: "Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)".

I'm not sure what the problem is.  If I remove all of the code I'm using and new up an SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA object without all of the Setup API calls, the call to delete works.  Basically, here's what I'm doing:

```
HDEVINFO hDevs = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&DiskClassGuid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);

SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devInterfaceData = {sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA)};
DWORD size(0);
SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevs, NULL, &DiskClassGuid, 0, &devInterfaceData);

PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pDetails(NULL);
SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevs, &devInterfaceData, pDetails, 0, &size, NULL);

pDetails = reinterpret_cast<PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA>(new BYTE[sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) + size]);
// zero allocated memory
pDetails->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevs, &devInterfaceData, pDetails, size, NULL, NULL);

delete[] pDetails;
```

When the program exits, or the delete[] is called, the assert that mentioned earlier shows up.  Please explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks,
Andy

UPDATE:
Forgot to add the definition of SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA.  That can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  However, it looks like this:

```
typedef struct _SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA {
  DWORD cbSize;
  TCHAR DevicePath[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
} SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA, *PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA;
```

Comment: Problem is solved.  The problem wasn't with this structure (though it had looked like it was).  There was another structure that I was using to retrieve location information from the registry.  I was overstepping that array at some point in the code which wasn't being detected until I was deleting that buffer.  I've corrected how I am using that buffer and the problem is no longer present.

This makes sense now.

Thanks in advance to anyone else who answers.  In fact, if I'm not doing the "correct" way, please educate me on how to do it correctly.

Andy

Comment: Also, your `delete[]` is incorrect. Should be `delete [] (BYTE *)pDetails` since you allocated it as a `BYTE` array, not a `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` array.

Comment: @Raymond Thank you for pointing that out.  I had assumed that using delete[] would be fine since it was deleting an array.

Comment: Yes, it's deleting an array, but without the cast, it's deleting the wrong type of array.